# facebook login using java

Tags: java, facebook

I am looking for a way to login to Facebook without a browser.

1. I want to obtain the access token without a browser.
2. Login is required in order to obtain the access token.

**-Login Java examples**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HttpUrlConnectionExample {
private List<String> cookies;
private HttpsURLConnection conn;
private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String url = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1";
    String facebook = "https://www.facebook.com/";
    HttpUrlConnectionExample http = new HttpUrlConnectionExample();
    // make sure cookies is turn on
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

    // 1. Send a "GET" request, so that you can extract the form's data.
    String page = http.GetPageContent(url);
    String postParams = http.getFormParams(page, "sainstia@gmail.com", "1111");

    // 2. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for
    // authentication
    http.sendPost(url, postParams);

    // 3. success then go to facebook.
    String result = http.GetPageContent(facebook);
    try {
        String content = result;
        File file = new File(".\\facebook_page.html");
        // if file doesnt exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.close();
        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    // Acts like a browser
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.facebook.com");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    }
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Send post request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    // System.out.println(response.toString());
}

private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    // default is GET
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    // act like a browser
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        }
    }
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    // Get the response cookies
    setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

    return response.toString();
}

public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    // Google form id
    Element loginform = doc.getElementById("login_form");
    Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
    List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
        String key = inputElement.attr("name");
        String value = inputElement.attr("value");
        if (key.equals("email"))
            value = username;
        else if (key.equals("pass"))
            value = password;
        paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
    }
    // build parameters list
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String param : paramList) {
        if (result.length() == 0) {
            result.append(param);
        } else {
            result.append("&" + param);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}

public List<String> getCookies() {
    return cookies;
}

public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
    this.cookies = cookies;
}
}

GetPageContent (String url) {
.....
.....

  setCookies (. conn.getHeaderFields () get ("Set-Cookie"));    
......
}
```

I could not have a "Set-Cookie" value.

I can not find the "Set-Cookie".

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Jsoup i just finished making a program that did exactly this it logged onto a website and then i could manipulate anything on the website as i needed as long as you match the `GET`requests you can log on to the wesbsite like this.

```
     Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

        response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .data("Action", "Login")
                .data("User", "My_UserName")
                .data("Password", "My_Password")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .timeout(50000)
                .execute();
```

Comment: cookies (response.cookies ()

This code is returned for a Null value.

Because the cookie is null it seems not to login.

Do you have a part that I missed?
Or, is there another way to solve this problem?